# Finding the smartest set from an array of numbers

Tags: python, programming-challenge, array

Is there any way to make this program run in better time ? While running, it is taking 1 second for the sample test case to pass and 5-10 seconds for the rest of the test cases.

**Problem statement**

> A smart-set is a set of distinct numbers in which all the elements have the same number of `1`s in their binary form. The set of all smallest elements from each smart-set 
>   that can be formed from a given array of distinct positive numbers is known as the smartest-set.
>
> So given an array of distinct numbers, outline the elements of the smartest-set in ascending sorted order.

Example

> Let the array be `{6 , 2 , 11 , 1 , 9 , 14 , 13 , 4 , 18}`.
>
> In binary form the set is `{110, 010, 1011, 0001, 1001, 1110, 1101, 0100, 10010}`.
>
> The smart-sets are `{1, 2, 4}, {6, 9, 18}, {11, 13, 14}`.
>
> The smartest-set is `{1,6,11}` as each element is the smallest element from each smart-set.

**Input Format**

The first line of input consists of an integer `t`. This is the number of test cases. For each test case, 
the first line of input contains an integer `n`. Here `n` is the number of elements in the array. The next line contains `n` space separated distinct integers which are the elements 
of the array.

**Output Format**

The output will space separated integer elements of the smartest-set in ascending order.

**Constraints**

> ```
> 0 < t < 1000 (This is the number of test cases )
> 2 < n < 10000 (This is the number of integer elements of the array) 
> 1 < Xi < 100000 (This is the size of each element of the array)
>
>
> SAMPLE STDIN 1
> 3
> 9
> 6 2 11 1 9 14 13 4 18
> 3
> 7 3 1
> 3
> 1 2 4
> SAMPLE STDOUT 
> 1 6 11
> 1 3 7
> 1
> ```

**Code**

```
test_case=input()
for case_num in range(int(test_case)):
    num_of_elements=input()
    arr=input()
    dictn={}
    #print (num_of_elements,arr)
    for bin_values in list(map(int,arr.split())):
        count=0
        for occurence in [int(x) for x in list('{0:0b}'.format(bin_values))]:
               if occurence==1:
                 count=count+1
        dictn[bin_values]=count
    v = {}

    for key, value in sorted(dictn.items()):
        v.setdefault(value, []).append(key)

    lst=[]
    for key,value in (v.items()):
        x=min(value)
        lst.append(str(x))
    s= ' '
    s = s.join(lst)
    print (s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Review

1. Don't `print()` but `return` variables, so other functions can reuse the outcome.
2. Split up your code into functions, for re usability and to easier test parts of your code.
3. Write test cases using the `unittest` module rather then doing it from the CLI every time
4. There are some code improvements as well,

   - You could benefit from the [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) module
   - An easier way to count the `"1"` in the binaray format is: `str(bin(ele)[2:]).count("1")`
   - You can benefit from list or dict comprehension, [see PEP202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

## Alternative

```
import unittest
from collections import defaultdict

def smartest_set(array):
    smart_sets = defaultdict(list)

    for element in array:
        num_of_ones = str(bin(element)[2:]).count("1")
        smart_sets[num_of_ones].append(element)

    # If you'd really want the output be printed, you can add a print statement in the function
    result = [min(e) for e in smart_sets.values()]
    print(result)
    return result

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_smartest_set(self):
        array = [6, 2, 11, 1, 9, 14, 13, 4, 18]
        expected = [1, 6, 11]
        self.assertEqual(expected, smartest_set(array))

        # More tests here...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Or a slightly faster approach storing the minimum value of the counts only

```
def smartest_set_2(array):
    smarts = {}
    for ele in array:
        num_of_ones = str(bin(ele)[2:]).count("1")
        smarts[num_of_ones] = min(ele, smarts.get(num_of_ones, float('inf'))
    return smarts.values()
```

Comment: It gave me this error: E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_smartest_set (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 17, in test_smartest_set
    self.assertEqual(expected == smartest_set(array))
TypeError: assertEqual() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.031s

FAILED (errors=1)

Comment: @codaholic *Edited*, my bad works now :)

Comment: I still don't have any idea where you are printing the output of the prgram

Comment: I currently don't, but you can call this function with any input and print it's results using, `print(smartest_set([array]))`

Comment: i tried adding the print statement in test class but it didn't work, can you please update your code @Ludisposed

Comment: @codaholic Sorry was busy, but if you'd really want to print the outcome you can add a print statement in the function. I've *Edited* once again

Comment: in the latest suggestion, you can prevent the `if` by doing `smarts[num_of_ones] = min(ele, smarts.get(num_of_ones, float('inf'))`

Comment: @MaartenFabré Good suggestion, I've incorperated that into my answer